# AJAX request doesn't load new requests

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have two buttons calling the **search_by_category** function which perform AJAX requests to the server (the server returns a JSON array of products).

**HTML Buttons :**

```
<button onclick="search_by_category('s')">
<button onclick="search_by_category('t')">
```

**The `search_by_category` function is:**

```
function search_by_category(product_category) {


  if (product_category == "") {
    $('#products_section').html('no products');
    return;
  }
  var xhttp;
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = show_products;
  xhttp.open("GET", "search_products.php?category="+product_category, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

**and the `show_product` function is:**

```
function show_products(){

    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

        var results=JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        if (results.length == 0) {
          $("#products_section").html("no product found");
        }
        else{
          $("#products_section").html("")
          var num_results=results.length;
          var product;
          for (var i=0;i<num_results;i++) {
            product= results[i];
            $("#products_section").append('<div> ..product information ..</div>');
           }
        }
}
}
```

If i first click on a button it works fine, but when i click on the other button it doesn't load the new content, anybody knows why?

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Comment: not a single error

Comment: What is shown in the network tab?

Comment: Is your php returning the same data every time?